# Tab content do not change when I click on the tabhost

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs, android-tabhost

I tried to create a bottom tabhost + fragment.

The problem are,

1) when I press on the tab button, it does not switch to another fragment , although my log show that it has entered on create view. I tired put a text view on every fragment but none of them show, so I suspect the fragment has not add on the framelayout id: realtabcontent?

2) The bottom tab host seems are "too bottom" so that the some of the tab 's bottom part
  is out of the screen

How to fix the problems? Thanks for helping

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    public FragmentTabHost tabHost;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabcontent);
        tabHost.addTab(
                setIndicator(this, tabHost.newTabSpec("About"),
                        R.drawable.ic_launcher), About.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(
                setIndicator(this, tabHost.newTabSpec("Camera"),
                        R.drawable.ic_launcher), CameraHandle.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(
                setIndicator(this, tabHost.newTabSpec("Gallery"),
                        R.drawable.ic_launcher), PhotoGallery.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(
                setIndicator(this, tabHost.newTabSpec("LeaderBoard"),
                        R.drawable.ic_launcher), LeaderBoard.class, null);
    }

    public TabSpec setIndicator(Context ctx, TabSpec spec, int resId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        ImageView logo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_logo);
        logo.setImageResource(resId);
        TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_title);
        text.setText(spec.getTag());
        return spec.setIndicator(v);
    }

}
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment (For each tab one fragment)

```
public class About extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.about, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextVsssiew" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a problem with your layout of the main activity - it had a height of 0px. You can use the hierarchyviewer from Android Tools to find out some detail of the views which are shown in your app - for more details see: (http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html)

try the following and go from there:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but the tab are at the top of layout but not at bottom of layout?

Answer (score 1):

You should try [like this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/54sRO1FE2hI) for your layout to set the tabs at the bottom of the screen.

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />
</LinearLayout>
```